# Onsenui - Infinite Scroll

Tags: onsen-ui

Jquery Infinite Scroll is not working with Onsen ui. Have any one implemented it?.

The same code works as a normal angular js app. But when i integrate it with onsen, only the first set of results are displayed. Other records are not getting displayed on scroll.

Comment: Kumar: Please update your post with your code. So that we could help you out.

Comment: Please find it here http://jsfiddle.net/rkrajeshkumar87/eBpLA/

Answer (score 4):

ons-list and ons-scroller has built in infinite-scroll. it's a hidden api but is fairly stable.

```
 <ons-scroll infinit-scroll-enable="true" on-scrolled="pagination.nextPage()" can-load="true" threshold='100'>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<ons-scroller infinit-scroll-enable="true" on-scrolled="pagination.nextPage()" can-load="true" threshold='100'>
```

Answer (score 1):

use infinit-scroll-enabale attribute for built infinit-scroll in ons-list and ons-scroller:

```
<ons-scroller infinit-scroll-enable="true" on-scrolled="nextItem();" threshold="0" >
                    <ons-list>
                        <ons-list-item ng-repeat="item in items" modifier="chevron" noslidingmenu>
                       {{item}}
                        </ons-list-item>
                    </ons-list>
                </ons-scroller>
```